# Why loading the data as a table produces different anova results to loading data as a stack?

Tags: r, stack, anova

Why loading the data as a table produces different anova results to loading data as a stack?

(1) I load the following table and obtain the anova.

```
31  42  14  80
42  26  25  106
84  21  19  83
26  60  36  69
14  35  44  48
16  80  28  76
29  49  80  39
32  38  76  84
45  65  15  91
30  71  82  39

> raw <- read.table("demotablenolabels.txt", sep="\t", header=FALSE)
> rawstack = stack(raw) 
> rawstack$sample = rep(rownames(raw),4)
> repeated = aov(values ~ ind + sample, data=rawstack)
> summary(repeated)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
ind          3   7553  2517.7   4.036 0.0171 *
sample       9   1565   173.9   0.279 0.9751  
Residuals   27  16843   623.8
```

(2) I save the following rawstack data to a file, load it and obtain a different anova result.

```
values  ind sample
31  V1  1
42  V1  2
84  V1  3
26  V1  4
14  V1  5
16  V1  6
29  V1  7
32  V1  8
45  V1  9
30  V1  10
42  V2  1
26  V2  2
21  V2  3
60  V2  4
35  V2  5
80  V2  6
49  V2  7
38  V2  8
65  V2  9
71  V2  10
14  V3  1
25  V3  2
19  V3  3
36  V3  4
44  V3  5
28  V3  6
80  V3  7
76  V3  8
15  V3  9
82  V3  10
80  V4  1
106 V4  2
83  V4  3
69  V4  4
48  V4  5
76  V4  6
39  V4  7
84  V4  8
91  V4  9
39  V4  10

> stackwithlabels <- read.table("demostackwithlabels.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
> repeatedstack = aov(values ~ ind + sample, data=stackwithlabels) 
> summary(repeatedstack)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
ind          3   7553  2517.7   4.918 0.00591 **
sample       1    492   492.1   0.961 0.33356   
Residuals   35  17916   511.9
```

(3) I convert the stackwithlabels back to a table and repeat the procedure and I get the orginal anova results (see 1).

```
> stackwithlabels[c(3)] <- list(NULL)
> rawwithoutlabels = unstack(stackwithlabels)
> restackwithoutlabels = stack(rawwithoutlabels)
> restackwithoutlabels$sample = rep(rownames(raw),4)
> rerepeatedstack = aov(values ~ ind + sample, data=restackwithoutlabels)
> summary(rerepeatedstack)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
ind          3   7553  2517.7   4.036 0.0171 *
sample       9   1565   173.9   0.279 0.9751  
Residuals   27  16843   623.8
```

Comment: Can you please format your question to differentiate between code and normal text?

Answer (score 0):

In your original data frame `rawstack`, `sample` is represented as a character vector.

```
str(rawstack$sample)
#  chr [1:40] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
```

Hence, `sample` is interpreted as a factor in `aov` and has 10 - 1 = 9 degress of freedom.

```
summary(aov(values ~ ind + sample, data = rawstack))
#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
# ind          3   7553  2517.7   4.036 0.0171 *
# sample       9   1565   173.9   0.279 0.9751  
# Residuals   27  16843   623.8                 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If you write the data into a text file and read the data back into R, `sample` is represented as a numeric vector.

```
stackwithlabels <- read.table(text = capture.output(write.table(rawstack)))
str(stackwithlabels$sample)
#  int [1:40] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Therefore the `aov`result is different. Note that `sample` now has 1 degree of freedom.

```
summary(aov(values ~ ind + sample, data = stackwithlabels))
#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
# ind          3   7553  2517.7   4.918 0.00591 **
# sample       1    492   492.1   0.961 0.33356   
# Residuals   35  17916   511.9                   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: How do I convert the numeric vector to a string vector?

Comment: I found it: stackwithlabels$sample &lt;- as.character(stackwithlabels$sample)

Comment: It's: stackwithlabels$sample <- as.character(stackwithlabels$sample)

Comment: Also set during read: stackwithlabels <- read.table("demostackwithlabels.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, colClasses= c("double", "character", "character"))